# Como faço para pegar há quanto tempo foi publicada uma notícia, e.x.: há 30 minutos, em php?

Tags: php

Seria o correto?

```
<?php 
  dateTime();
?>
```

Pelas pesquisas que faço pelo Google, ainda não encontrei uma resposta válida.

Comment: Você pode usar a função date_diff para comparar a data da publicação com a data atual, se você puder postar um exemplo simples do seu código ficaria mais fácil explicar.

Comment: Você quer exibir essa informação em formato amigável (como "postada há 30 minutos"), ou quer fazer cálculos com ela? Como a data de postagem está armazenada no seu banco de dados?

Comment: Olá, Anderson B. Furlan. Boa dica, vou tentar fazer pra vê se dá certo. Obrigado. bfavaretto, minha intenção é esta mesma.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando as funções time() strtotime() e comparando as datas, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
class Data {

public static function ExibirTempoDecorrido($date)
{
    if(empty($date))
    {
        return "Informe a data";
    }

    $periodos = array("segundo", "minuto", "hora", "dia", "semana", "mês", "ano", "década");
    $duracao = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

    $agora = time();
    $unix_data = strtotime($date);

    // check validity of date
    if(empty($unix_data))
    {  
        return "Bad date";
    }

    // is it future date or past date
    if($agora > $unix_data) 
    {  
        $diferenca     = $agora - $unix_data;
        $tempo         = "atrás";
    } 
    else 
    {
        $diferenca     = $unix_data - $agora;
        $tempo         = "agora";
    }

    for($j = 0; $diferenca >= $duracao[$j] && $j < count($duracao)-1; $j++) 
    {
        $diferenca /= $duracao[$j];
    }

    $diferenca = round($diferenca);

    if($diferenca != 1) 
    {
        $periodos[$j].= "s";
    }

    return "$diferenca $periodos[$j] {$tempo}";
}
}
```

Chamando a função:

```
print_r(Data::ExibirTempoDecorrido(date("12/31/2010")));
```

Você terá o resultado:

```
3 anos atrás
```

[Fonte](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=37242#p37242)